# ELF segments mem size vs. file size

Tags: elf

I have read a couple of ELF specification documents but haven't found answers for the below questions yet

1) When segment memory size is greater than segment file size, should the ELF segment downloader fill the segment in memory with zeros as specified by memsize?

2) Can there be a case where a section should be filled with a constant other than zero, i.e. a general case "constant fill" section?

3) What is the right way to identify a .const segment in elf executable file?

The per-section flags value does not have such information and seems to be limited.I have seen implementations of ELF segment downloader where they don't download segments with file size of zero at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a long over-due answer, but anyway..

1. When segment memory size is greater than segment file size, should the ELF segment downloader fill the segment in memory with zeros as specified by memsize?
   ==> I think so. Some sections like .BSS (unintialized data) don't have space in the elf file but should have space in memory when loaded uninitialized. But C run-time initializes the data with zero before going into main() I understand.
2. Can there be a case where a section should be filled with a constant other than zero, i.e. a general case "constant fill" section?
   ==> Yes, I remember we can set fill pattern in a section. Search shows me FILL(expression) attribute.
3. What is the right way to identify a .const segment in elf executable file?
   ==> I think you could do something like

   unsigned int __attribute__((__section__ (".const") FILE("0x1234"))) data[0x1000];

?